# Cooking Small White Navy's giving me issues

Tags: beans

how long must I cook small white navy beans in my soup to get soft?  Seems like it is taking too long. So far I have cooked 4 hours!

Comment: Did you start with dried? Were they prepared before cooking (re-hydrated)?

Comment: How long did you soak them beforehand? How old is the pack?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your beans are too old.  Buy a new pack in another store and start over.  It really shouldn't take more than an hour or so for beans to cook, especially if you have pre-soaked them (overnight in cold water, or an hour in boiling water).